# New User Registration email

Tags: users, email, user-registration

I am receiving an email notification whenever a new user is added to my site. I need to change the default 'send-to' address. It is using a personal email, rather than my 'webmaster' email. Where is the setting for this?

Answer (score 0):

In the admin interface under **Settings > General** there is a field named **E-mail Address**.  Unless you have a plugin managing your user registration separately, this should be the default email address for registration confirmations.

Comment: Thanks, didn't want to sniff all over for that.